# Dynamic column using Linq EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to create a *Linq lambda* statement using *EF*.

I have 4 fixed table (not including reference table) that need to *Join*. But the column name that need to be retrieve is base on the column name from the reference table.

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, `DB_TABLE` column is the column for which table that need to be join (please ignore `.SHIPTO` & `.CONSIGNEE`, just `REL_BATCH_PARTY`). 
The `DB_FIELD` column is the column that i need to select.

**Example**

```
SUBSTR({0}CONTACT_PHONE,0,8)
```

So i need to be like `SUBSTR(REL_BATCH_PARTY.CONTACT_PHONE,0,8)`.
{0} will be replace by the table name.

Here is my final sql statement base on the reference table:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT
     (SELECT substr(REL_BATCH_PARTY.CONTACT_PHONE, 0, 8)
      FROM REL_BATCH_PARTY
      WHERE REL_BATCH_PARTY.REL_BATCH_ID = REL_BATCH.ID
        AND REL_BATCH_PARTY.TYPE_CODE = 'SHIPTO') CONTACT_PHONE_SUBSTR,

     (SELECT REL_BATCH_PARTY.CONTACT_PHONE
      FROM REL_BATCH_PARTY
      WHERE REL_BATCH_PARTY.REL_BATCH_ID = REL_BATCH.ID
        AND REL_BATCH_PARTY.TYPE_CODE = 'SHIPTO') CONTACT_PHONE,
          TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd-MM-yyyy') TODAY,
          REL_BATCH.REL_NO,

     (SELECT REL_BATCH_PARTY.ADDR01
      FROM REL_BATCH_PARTY
      WHERE REL_BATCH_PARTY.REL_BATCH_ID = REL_BATCH.ID
        AND REL_BATCH_PARTY.TYPE_CODE = 'CONSIGNEE') ADDR01,
          REL_BATCH_CONTAINER.CONTAINER_NO,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REL_BATCH.ID
                            ORDER BY REL_BATCH_CONTAINER.ID, REL_BATCH_PARTY.TYPE_CODE) num
   FROM REL_BATCH REL_BATCH
   LEFT JOIN REL_BATCH_PARTY REL_BATCH_PARTY ON REL_BATCH.ID = REL_BATCH_PARTY.REL_BATCH_ID
   LEFT JOIN REL_BATCH_CONTAINER REL_BATCH_CONTAINER ON REL_BATCH.ID = REL_BATCH_CONTAINER.REL_BATCH_ID WHERE ..... )A
WHERE A.NUM = 1
```

Is there anyway to create using Linq Lambda expression?.

The `DB_FIELD` column & row will be dynamic base on user input in the reference table. The `DB_TABLE` will only using this 4 table (`REL_BATCH`, `REL_BATCH_PARTY`, `REL_BATCH_ATTR`, `REL_BATCH_CONTAINER`). The relationship is `ID` in `REL_BATCH` will have foreign key in all other 3 tables.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you make any effort?

Comment: It just took 5 minutes to format your post, please spend the same amount of time in the future making it readable

Comment: sorry for that..

Comment: The basic answer is not unless you want to write an expression generator, or put every possible field name in the query with guarded expression matching against the `DB_FIELD` column. LINQ is strongly typed, you can't have expressions changing to match fields of differing types. What would the type of the result be? Of course, there is always [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions).